# What is the use of SWN SWO SWP file extensions?

Tags: filenames, package.json

I came across these files in one of the git repository

- package-lock.json.swn
- package-lock.json.swp
- package-lock.json.swo

Answer (score 1):

The *package-lock.json.swp* file is a Vim swapfile and was probably just accidentally added to the repository.

Vim creates .swp files for two main purposes: recovery and avoiding conflicts when multiple instances of Vim are editing the same file.

Either the developer should be more careful when adding the files to the repository, or they can add the .swp extension to .gitignore.